# How to do transition to next frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I'm a beginner in AS3 and Flash.
There are index.swf and intro.swf, which is loaded in first frame of index file.
In intro.swf I placed a button, which should send command to index.swf main timeline to go to frame 2.
If i use `parent`'s construction, i will try to access level that is not present in intro file at the moment of compilation. So, how can I do it?

Comment: Your question seems very unclear. Can you elaborate please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should define which method you use to load one swf to another. On this depends what will be the reference to the top level.
If you used `flash.display.Loader` then from MainTimeline of loaded swf to MainTimeline of loader swf (if you load not inside so object but create `Loader` itself by code on Maintimeline - reference will be

```
MovieClip(parent.parent)
```

Loaded swf root stored inside `Loader` instance at `content` property, that why there is two `parent`. And data-type convertion should used because `parent` return reference as `DisplayObject` and thats block you from access it properties.